# llvm - fastest way to check if two files of code (.ll) are the same

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc

Is it possible to write a pass that can check if two .ll files are same or not? And if they're not, then give a value of how different they are?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether the two .ll files are same or not you can use **llvm-diff** filename1 filename2

I think its better to use **vimdiff** instead of **llvm-diff** if you just want to compare the two .ll files

Comment: llvm-diff just gives an error once a slightest difference comes and exits. I need a whole log of all the differences. Also, it does this for a simple piece of code where the only difference between the two files is variable renaming and statement reordering. For example, doing 
return a + b in one file and return q + p in the other (where a is the same as p and b is the same as q).

Comment: An alternative to vimdiff would be to use the regular UNIX diff command with the -y command